# Print the positions of a character, including the positions of space between them, in a string

Tags: java, string

How can I print the positions of a character, including the positions of space between them, in a string without using built in functions?

For example:
let the string input be "i love my india"

char input ='i'

output must be: positions of 'i' are:0 10 13

i have tried this:

```
    String str="i love my india";
    char c='i';
    char ch[]=str.toCharArray();

    int pos=0;
    for(int i=0;i<str.length();i++)
    {
        if(ch[i]==c)
        {
            System.out.print(pos+" ");
        }
        pos++;
    }
```

i got output for above logic, but wen i try to use scanner class, the output is wrong: whats wrong with the below code?

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    Scanner sc1=new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("enter the string:");
    String str=sc1.next();
    System.out.println("---------------------------");
    Scanner sc2=new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("enter the character:");
    char c=sc2.next().charAt(0);

    char ch[]=str.toCharArray();

    int pos=0;
    for(int i=0;i<str.length();i++)
    {
        if(ch[i]==c)
        {
            System.out.print(pos+" ");
        }
        pos++;
    }
}
```

Comment: please define a `built-in function` set of funcions

Comment: @TheLostMind yep, removed that c:

Comment: as the both answers down replace next with nextline and it works

Answer (score 0):

Use `scanner.nextLine()` which reads the *entire line* instead of `scanner.next()` which reads only the first word. print the value of `str` and see what it contains :)

Next, you need only 1 scanner. Remove `Scanner sc2=new Scanner(System.in)`; Use sc1 instead of `sc2`

Answer (score 0):

Only replace String str=sc1.next(); by String str=sc1.nextLine(); this will work.
plz try it.